# Continuity of Parabolic Evolution Equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimal-control, parabolic-pde, optimal-transport

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set with smooth boundary and $V$ be a (strongly) convex, smooth function. For the equation
$$
\partial_t\rho_t = \nabla\cdot(\rho_t\nabla(\log\rho_t + V))
$$
with no-flux boundary condition $\rho_tn\cdot\nabla(\log\rho_t +V) = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$, let $\rho_t$ be a weak solution starting from $\rho_0$, where $m < \rho_0(x) < M$ for some constant $m, M > 0$.

My questions are, is $\rho_t$ differentiable w.r.t $t$? Is $\nabla\log\rho_t$ uniformly bounded on $\Omega$? And under what conditions, there are constants $\alpha, \tau > 0$ s.t.
$$
\Big|\Big|\nabla\log\frac{\rho_t}{\rho_0}\Big|\Big|_{\infty} \lesssim t^{\alpha}
$$
for all $0\leq t\leq\tau$?

Comment: why not applying chain rule and simplify of $\rho\nabla \log \rho$ to $\nabla \rho$?

Comment: @daw I guess it won't help too much.

Comment: then it is a standard linear parabolic equation...

Comment: @daw So, any reference for that? The related material on Evans book has differenent boundary conditions, and I didn't see any material to give the bound of supnorm of $\nabla\log\rho_t$